# Create new pandas column based on categorical values in other column (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a data frame with country and traffic columns:

```
Country    |   Traffic
  US            8687
  Italy         902834
  Germany       2343
  Brazil        4254
  France        23453
```

I want to add a third column called "Region" to this data frame. It would look like this:

```
 Country    |   Traffic   | Region
  US            8687         US
  Italy         902834       EU
  Germany       2343         EU
  Brazil        4254         LA
  France        23453        EU
```

The following code works if I have only two Regions. I am looking more for an `if/else`, `map`, or `lambda` statement:

```
df['Region'] = np.where(df['Country'] == 'US', 'US', 'EU')
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
region_from_country = {
    'US': 'US', 
    'Italy': 'EU',
    'Germany': 'EU',
    'Brazil': 'LA', 
    'France': 'EU',
}
df['Region'] = df['Country'].replace(region_from_country)
```

The keys in the dictionary are the countries and the values are the corresponding regions.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach is this:

```
dict ={'US':'US','Italy':'EU','Germany':'EU','Brazil':'LA','France':'EU'}

df['Region']=df['Country'].apply(lambda x : dict[x])
```